# Php utf8 failing in mysql but ok on csv import

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

This is on my windows test platform.

I have the following csv:

```
You have signed out successfully!,ar,لقد خرجت بنجاح!
```

I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `translations` (
  `sourcephrase` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `language` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `translatedphrase` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sourcephrase`,`language`),
  KEY `language` (`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

If I load this csv into table (via mysql workbench, import csv), I get the data just fine.

```
sourcephrase, language, translation
You have signed out successfully!   ar  لقد خرجت بنجاح!
```

If instead I run this php code (where psquery is just execute a prepared statement):

```
    $sourcephrase="You have signed out successfully!";
    $language="ar";
    $translated="لقد خرجت بنجاح!";
    $sql = "insert into translations (sourcephrase, language, translatedphrase) values (?,?,?)";
    $this->DB->psquery($sql, array("sss", $sp, $language, $translated));
```

The table contains the following data:

```
You have signed out successfully!   ar  Ù„Ù‚Ø¯ Ø®Ø±Ø¬Øª Ø¨Ù†Ø¬Ø§Ø­!
```

Why am I getting a different result in php ? (I know its something utf8 related, but I can't see what). I don't believe it's mysql related, as the csv import is just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ù„Ù‚Ø¯ Ø®Ø±Ø¬Øª Ø¨Ù†Ø¬Ø§Ø­!` is Mojibake for the desired string.  See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for the likely causes, best practice, and debugging techniques.

Probably this item is relevant to your PHP connection:  "The connection when INSERTing and SELECTing text needs to specify utf8 or utf8mb4."

Comment: Wow, that link is pure gold.I wish I could upvote multiple times. Mr James, you are the business for utf-8. I can't decide whether to bookmark your answer or your name!

Comment: @DavidShields - Hehe.  Thanks.  I have struggled for years to consolidate scattered advice into that single location.  (You could upvote the question _and_ the answer.)

Comment: Done, and done. Because, well, why wouldn't you ? Well deserved upvotes.